# How to upload picture with Angular File Upload (ng-file-upload) to backend Laravel/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I having been trying to wrap my head around ng-file-upload but without much success.

I'm trying to upload a picture using **ng-file-upload** to backend PHP/Laravel

**I have this in my angular controller:**

```
$scope.upload = function (file) {

    Upload.upload({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/profile/photo/add',
        file: file,
        sendFieldsAs: 'form'
        //fileFormDataName: 'photo'
    })

    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          dd(data);
          console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + data);
     })

    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          dd(data);
          console.log('error status: ' + status);
     })
```

**HTML Template for ng file upload:**

```
<div ngf-select="upload($file, $event)"
  ngf-change="upload($file, $event)"
  ngf-pattern="'image/*'"
  ngf-capture="capture"
  ngf-drag-over-class="{accept:'dragover', reject:'dragover-err',      delay:100}"
  ngf-validate="{size: {min: 10, max: '1MB'}, width: {min: 200, max:10000},  height: {min: 200, max: 300}, duration: {min: '10s', max: '5m'}, pattern: 'image/*'}"
  ngf-keep="false"
  ngf-allow-dir="true" class="drop-box"
  ngf-drop-available="dropAvailable">Select Photo,
  <span ng-show="dropAvailable">Drop/Paste Photo</span>
```

**I have also created a route/controller in Laravel**

```
public function postAdd(PhotoRequest $request)
{
    //Here am just checking if file is valid but it always return false and uploads an unreadable file to /uploads/profile folder 
    if ($request->file('file')->isValid() && $request->hasFile('file')) {
        $request->file('file')->move(public_path('/uploads/profile/'));
        return json_encode($request->file('file')->isValid()); //returns false
    }else{
        return response()->json(['file not found']);
    }

 }
```

**When examined in chrome console, the output looks like this:**
[image]

**These unreadable files were uploaded**

[image]

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: When you are upload image? instant after image choosing or after clicking submit button?

Comment: @Paresh Gami If I understand you, upload starts instantly after image selection, since I'm using this: `ngf-change="upload($file, $event)"`

Comment: In the browser's network tab compare the post request being sent to the server with what Laravel server would expect or a working example that would five you a clue.

Comment: Also are you sure the files are unreadable? It might be just their names that are not correct the content might be correct.